# Java serialized object is empty

Tags: java, serialization

The product I work on uses a lot of Java serialization. In the 10 years the product has been active, this problem has apparently never occurred before this year. This year, it's occurred twice. We have not released a new software version in about two years.

The issue is that occasionally, a serialized file (and only one particular serialized file, no others) becomes empty. That is, it is the correct length, but when opening in a hex editor, the contents of the file are entirely 0s. This serialized file is not written any differently than any other code-wise. We log practically everything and no exceptions have been thrown on machines affected by this problem.

Our current workaround is to ignore this file and rewrite a proper version if we encounter a StreamCorruptedException when reading it. This only works at all because the data in the file is currently not used, but we'd like to implement a use for it at some point in the future, and to do that we obviously have to solve this.

Here is an example of a properly serialized file and one where the issue occurred:
[image]

My question is

1. Has anyone encountered this specific issue before?
2. How would one go about solving an issue this rare and unpredictable?

Comment: Have you checked to see if there was anything to be serialized?  Or check the data source first.

Comment: In section 6.4 of the [Java Object Stream Protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html#10258) it states that the grammar of the stream requires it start with a stream magic and version, which would be 0xACED0005 for stream magic and protocol version 5, which is reflected in the first file above. If there was no data to be written, it would at least write the stream header if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Is there anything unusual about how you’re creating the ObjectOutputStream?  Can you show the code that creates it, and the code that creates the OutputStream it wraps?